# How to hide elements of webpage shown by WebView in Xamarin forms

Tags: javascript, c#, html, xamarin.forms, webview

I have a website and now want to make iOS/Android APP to show content of my website. I plan to use **Xamarin.Forms** and **WebView**. The problem is, APP doesn't need to show as much as website, so I want to hide some elements of webpages. For example, there is an element whose id is "test", I want to use **EvaluateJavaScriptAsync** to hide it.

I tried

```
WebView WebSiteView = new WebView();

WebSiteView.Source = WebUrl;

WebSiteView.EvaluateJavaScriptAsync("document.getElementById('test').style.display = 'none';");
```

But it doesn't work. Could someone tell me if this can work and how? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you invoke the method `EvaluateJavaScriptAsync` directly , the `WebView` hasn't been
full initialized yet .

So you could invoke the JS code in the event **Navigated**

```
WebSiteView.Navigated += (o, s) => {
  WebSiteView.EvaluateJavaScriptAsync("document.getElementById('test').style.display = 'none';");
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

For webview2 (WinUI3):
You can get access to webview2 core and use the DOMContentLoaded event. If you use the navigationcompleted event you will briefly see the item you are hiding since the page navigation is completed before you set its display property to none. When using the DOMContentLoaded event I have found that I never see the item when navigating to a new page.

```
private async void MyWebView2_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await MyWebView2.EnsureCoreWebView2Async();
    MyWebView2.CoreWebView2.DOMContentLoaded += CoreWebView2_DOMContentLoaded;
}

private void CoreWebView2_DOMContentLoaded(Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.CoreWebView2 sender, Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.CoreWebView2DOMContentLoadedEventArgs args)
{
    sender.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.getElementById('buyAppButton').style.display = 'none';");
}
```